# How to filter based on any letter typed in autocomplete (Dango)

Tags: python, django, search, filter, autocomplete

The process for autocomplete in Django works fine.

My issue is that i want to filter not only by first letter in a model field `first_name` but for any letter a first_name might have.

For example imagine that I stored in the column `first_name` the below values in my table Profile:

**Louna
Lola
Linda
Mola
Rouna**

By typing L the search returns Louna,Lola,Linda.

I want by typing **na** the search to return Lou**na** and Rou**na**

Any ideas?

My class:

```
class ProfileAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
        def get_queryset(self):
            # Don't forget to filter out results depending on the visitor !
            # if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            #     return Profile.objects.none()
            qs = Profile.objects.all()
            if self.q:
                qs = qs.filter(first_name__istartswith=self.q)

            return qs
```

My model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.first_name+ " " +self.last_name
```

My form:

```
from django import forms

    from .models import Profile
    from dal import autocomplete
    from django.forms import ModelChoiceField



    class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
        first_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Profile.objects.all(),widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='profile-autocomplete'))


        class Meta:
                model = Profile
                fields = ('__all__')
```

My template:

```
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<div>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>

{{ form.media }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for [`contains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#contains) or possibly [`icontains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#icontains). These are case-sensitive and case insensitive containment test.

The resulting code is as follows:

```
qs = qs.filter(first_name__contains=self.q)
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?